# How to dynamically access string value?

Tags: python

If I define 2 strings as:

```
Str1 = "select * from tableA"

Str2 = "select * from tableB"
```

Now when i = 1, Str1 value should be retrieved and when i = 2 , str2 value should be retrieved. How to dynamically access string value?

```
Src=“Str”
for i in range(1,3):
  ********
  print(new_str)
```

How do I display Str1 value first and then Str2 next in above code ?

Comment: src = [Str1, Str2]; print(src)

Comment: If you want to select the strings via a number, they should be elements in a list or dictionary.

Comment: use an `if` statement?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you could use eval.

```
Str1 = "select * from tableA"
Str2 = "select * from tableB"
for i in range(1, 3):
    print(eval('Str{}'.format(i)))
```

To add a little protection from errors you can check if the variable exists like so:

```
Str1 = "select * from tableA"
Str2 = "select * from tableB"
for i in range(0, 10):
    ret = 'Str{}'.format(i)
    if ret in locals():
        print(eval(ret))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
>>> str1 = 'foo'
>>> str2 = 'bar'
>>> str3 = 'baz'
>>> for i in range(1, 4): print(eval(f'str{i}'))
...
foo
bar
baz
```

But *don't*. Rather, use a list or dictionary. This is exactly what these data types are for.

```
>>> str_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> str_dict = {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar', 3: 'baz'}
>>> for s in str_list: print(s)
...
foo
bar
baz
>>> for k, v in str_dict.items(): print(f'{k}: {v}')
...
1: foo
2: bar
3: baz
```

Answer (score -1):

A replacement for eval in this case:

```
>>> str1 = 'foo'
>>> str2 = 'bar'
>>> str3 = 'baz'
>>> for i in range(1, 4): print(globals()[(f'str{i}')])
...
foo
bar
baz
```

Looping over a list or using a dictionary is a better option.